# Where is the update site for `org.eclipse.fx.javafx` (Unable to locate installable unit)?

Tags: javafx, osgi, p2, efxclipse

I have a plugin based product file using:

- org.eclipse.fx.javafx
- org.eclipse.fx.osgi

I think these plugins come from the [e(fx)clipse](http://efxclipse.org/) project.

I am trying to build a target file providing those plugins (a maven+tycho build will be my next step). I thought I could get them on this p2 update site:

`http://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/updates-released/1.0.0/site`

My target file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?pde version="3.8"?><target name="my_target" sequenceNumber="1">
  <locations>
    <location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="planner" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
      <unit id="org.eclipse.fx.javafx" version="2.2.0.201408150502"/>
      <unit id="org.eclipse.fx.osgi" version="1.0.0.201408150502"/>
      <repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/updates-released/1.0.0/site"/>
    </location>
  </locations>
</target>
```

But I get this error: "Unable to locate installable unit org.eclipse.fx.javafx".

[image: Target Editor Screenshot]

If I edit the location, I can select one of those items:

[image: Edit content Wizard]

I have the same behavior with the nightly update site:

`http://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/updates-nightly/site`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should NOT use this update-site to setup a target platform! Use `http://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/runtime-shared-released/1.1.0/site` when creating target platforms.

[image: Edit Software site screenshot].

The XML content of the Target file looks like this:

```
<location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="slicer" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
  <unit id="org.eclipse.fx.runtime.min.feature.feature.group" version="1.1.0.201411050602"/>
  <repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/runtime-shared-released/1.1.0/site/"/>
</location>
```

The feature with minimal content is described here: [Easier runtime consumption through special features](http://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2014/11/05/efxclipse-1-1-new-features-easier-runtime-consumption-through-special-features/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply and the pointer on your blog. I am happy to have asked this question, because this runtime update site is not mentioned on the website: https://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse (or at least I could not find the information). In addition I could not find  `org.eclipse.fx.runtime.min.feature` on the `runtine-released - 1.1.0` update site. Should I use `org.eclipse.fx.runtime.feature.feature.group`
or `org.eclipse.fx.core.feature.feature.group` ?

Comment: Ups the minimal feature is at http://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/runtime-shared-released/1.1.0/site

Comment: One more note - if you build for Mars the feature is also in the simrel repo

Comment: By Mars simrel repo you mean `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars`? (Personally I am building for Luna, but it might help others)

Answer (score 0):

in this there is org.eclipse.fx.*
http://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/updates-nightly/site

if you have problem you can dowload in zip:
http://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/updates-nightly/site_assembly.zip